# Linux server user details

Tags: linux, rhel, rhel6

in linux server someone copied the home directory to the different location . how to find which particular user who has carried the copy operation in the RHEL 6 server.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on various things. If the `sudo` was used then the command should be logged in `/var/log/secure`.

You can execute this script to check command history of users on a server.

```
# the command that moved/copied home directory
# COMMAND=mv
COMMAND=cp
for user in $(ls /home/); do
    # I assume that users use bash as their shell
    sudo grep --with-filename ${COMMAND} /home/${user}/.bash_history 2>/dev/null
done
```